# My_Controller not found on server CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Dear: helper i run on wamp local server is working fine but i have problem with My_Controller is not found is core folder. I already insert My_Controller in core folder `"core/My_Controller.php"` and in config.php i already insert config too `"$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';"` anyone help me please?

```
Fatal error: Class 'MY_Controller' not found in /home/phnompen/public_html/my_side_url/application/controllers/Controller.php on line 9

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Class 'MY_Controller' not found

Filename: controllers/Controller.php

Line Number: 9

Backtrace:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make you you have the MY in your file name not My

```
core/My_Controller.php
```

Change to

```
core/MY_Controller.php
```

Same as in my comment.